# Android Regex Turkish Character Not Allowed (i,ş,ö...)

Tags: regex

I use that regex String:

```
final String regexStr = "^[a-zA-Z ]+$";
```

But I can not write i,ö,ü ... 
But I can u,ı,u...

TextChangedListener:

```
        txtSicilAdi.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            String text = txtSicilAdi.getText().toString();
            if (text.length() > 0) {
                if (!text.substring(text.length() - 1).matches(regexStr))
                {
                    txtSicilAdi.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                    txtSicilAdi.setSelection(txtSicilAdi.length());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c){ }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a){ }
    });
```

Comment: You can try `^[\p{L} ]+$`

Comment: That is works. Thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. If it still solve your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/6403828). It will help other people that have the same question to find the solution you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take into account all letters and not only not-accentuated ones, you can use `\p{L}`.

Your regex should then look like this:

```
^[\p{L} ]+$
```

Comment: interesting, didn't know about `\p{L}`. After reading the docs i add `\p{M}` to match letters with marks on them too.

Comment: @tfidelis I didn't know about `\p{M}`. I'm not sure it is needed. Which characters that can be used does it add?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
final String regexStr = "^[a-zA-Z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ ]+$";
```

Comment: This works but i can not write little "ı" only. Example : "pıtır"

Comment: @mobileprogramming i added the character "ı" in regex.